# how to stop repeat click to post ajax in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use django create a website .and i just write a vote page ,when people click ,it will post data via jquery ajax .it work well
here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>vote</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $(".post_up").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/article/{{post.id}}/vote_up/",
            type:'post',              
            success:function(msg){
                var beforevote = $(".btn").text();                 
                if (msg==0){
                    $(".pop_up_vote").empty().text("thanks,i get your vote!").show(300).delay(7000).hide(300);
                      };
                      if (msg==1){
                    $(".pop_up_vote").empty().text("you already voted,do not need vote again").show(300).delay(7000).hide(300);
                };
         })

 })
 </script>

 <a href="javascript:" class="btn_gray_light post_up"><span><i class="icon_add"></i>vote</span></a> 
 <div class ="pop_up_vote" >
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Everything works well, and I just found the problem. I can not stop repeatedly click vote.
If I click repeatedly
 `<a href="javascript:" class="btn_gray_light post_up"><span><i class="icon_add"></i>vote</span></a>`

it repeate show up the pop_up message,"i already voted ,do not vote again."
so i thought ,i may solve the problem by remove the class `post_up`  ,in this way ,people can not activate ajax post function 
so i add **$(this).removeClass();**

```
  $(function(){

    $(".post_up").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/article/{{post.id}}/vote_up/",
            type:'post',              
            success:function(msg){
                var beforevote = $(".btn").text();                 
                if (msg==0){
                    $(".pop_up_vote").empty().text("thanks,i get your vote!").show(300).delay(7000).hide(300);
                      };
                      if (msg==1){
                    $(".pop_up_vote").empty().text("you already voted,do not need vote again").show(300).delay(7000).hide(300);
                };
        })

})
```

When I remove the class, I still have the problem regarding ajax. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : http://api.jquery.com/one/.

```
$('.post_up').one('click', function () {
```

You can re-bind the same handler once Ajax is done :

```
$('.post_up').one('click', function handler() {
    var el = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/article/{{post.id}}/vote_up/',
        type: 'post',  
        success: function (msg) {
            $(el).one('click', handler);
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/CVm37/.

Comment: all i want is that ,once the ajax send the data success,the click disabled,people can not click the button to send the data agaian .because ,every time ,it click the button ,client side will send the data again ,and show up the pop_up massage .if the speed quick enough,it will pop up lots of same messages.

Comment: @zzlettle Read the doc. This is exactly what `.one()` does.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the behaviour is already set for the link, so removing the class won't do anything

try this instead

```
$(".post_up").unbind("click");
```